# Opening a file in a Metro app from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-8, microsoft-metro, command-line-arguments, windows-10

I need a way to open a file in a Metro app from command line.

So far I've figured out how to start the app from command line without any third-party scripts

```
explorer shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Reader_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Reader
```

but I haven't been able to figure out how to include a file name yet.

Launching

```
explorer shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Reader_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Reader example.pdf
```

just opens up a default explorer window.

Any idea from Windows 8 experts on how to accomplish this **without** any third-party tools/cmdlets/etc.?

*Note*: In fact I'm using Windows 10 but I guess if there's a Windows 8 / 8.1 way to do it, it'll work for 10, too.

Answer (score 9):

If you're still looking for the answer, the best way to *open a file in a metro app* is to use an execution string like a normal app protocol does. The execution string looks like this:

```
bingnews:[arguments, can be left blank.]
microsoftvideo:[arguments, can be left blank.]
netflix:[arguments, can be left blank.]
```

So, to start up netflix, it's as simple as typing in `Start netflix:` into the command line.

To find the execution string for an app, go here: Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations

---

More info and examples can be found here.

http://windowsitpro.com/windows-8/opening-windows-8-apps-command-prompt-or-script

http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/10/28/launch-windows-8-metro-apps-from-a-desktop-shortcut-or-command-line/

---

PLEASE NOTE: To open an app WITHOUT A PROTOCOL (One not listed in the registry or under "Set Associations") use OP's method:

`explorer shell:AppsFolder\[appuid]![appfullname]`

The app UID is the folder name without the version number. For example,

4DF9E0F8.Netflix_***2.11.0.8_x64***__mcm4njqhnhss8

becomes

4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8

The app fullname is the `[App author].[App name]` For example, `4DF9E0F8.Netflix`. 4DF9E0F8 is the author, and Netflix is the name.

Put it all together to get

`explorer shell:AppsFolder\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8!4DF9E0F8.Netflix`

Comment: This is tantalizingly close to what I wanted, except how do I know if the metro-style app is the default, and therefore, to use this method?

Comment: To know more about protocols, and which app will open by a specific protocol, open `Settings`, choose `System`, click on the `Default apps` tab on the sidebar, and scroll down until you find `Choose default apps by protocol`.

Answer (score 4):

Store Apps can only be started by the shell. So try this:

```
explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

Or from run (Win+R):

```
shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

Answer (score 2):

If the app is the default handler then you can just launch the file or protocol. There isn't a good in-box way to launch a file into a non-default handler from the command line.

Windows Store apps aren't designed to run from the command line and there isn't a straightforward way to launch them from the command line. Apps which handle specific files or protocols receive them through [FileActivatedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.activation.fileactivatedeventargs.aspx) or [ProtocolActivatedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.activation.protocolactivatedeventargs.aspx) rather than command line arguments

You could write a launcher app which uses CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager's [IApplicationActivationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902(v=vs.85).aspx) to [ActivateForFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706904(v=vs.85).aspx) a specific app.

Comment: I could launch it using "start path/to/file.pdf", but this opens a command prompt on older systems.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found to pass command-line arguments to the executable targeted by the shell command is via the Windows start command.

Using your example, you would end up with this:

`start "" shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.Reader_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Reader example.pdf`

I don't have Microsoft.Reader installed, so I can't test that. However, I can verify that this pattern works with Windows Terminal. In this case, I pass it a command-line argument to tell it which profile I want to open.

`start "" shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App new-tab -p "GitBash"`

The first argument to the start command here — the empty string — is just the title of the window.

You can also pair this with `cmd /c`, which I've found is necessary for some launcher applications, such as my personal favorite, SlickRun:

`cmd /c start "" shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App new-tab -p "GitBash"`

I have a [blog post](https://poetengineer.postach.io/post/how-to-open-windows-modern-app-from-the-command-line) with more info on running Modern apps from the command line, which you might find helpful in constructing these ridiculously obtuse commands.

Comment: Works. Found after much research. Thanks. But I want to put this whole thing with the argument in a shortcut and that only works with cmd /c. But the cmd window blinks which spoils the fun.

Comment: @user173399 - A variety of workarounds to the briefly-visible-cmd-window problem can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works on Windows 8, but on Windows 10 I use this:

```
cmd /C start <app-name>:
```

For example, to start Slack:

```
cmd /C start slack:
```